# Access Gatsby frontmatter for static pages from layout

Tags: gatsby

As I understand it, for static pages you define frontmatter this way:

```js
exports.data = {
  title: 'Projects'
}
```

What is the simplest/cleanest way to access the title from within your main layout?

Comment: Can you clarify what type of page you're creating? Something like `src/pages/foo.js`?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Just normal pages for which I want to assign a title that can then be extracted inside the layout and used for design/layout purposes. For example title 'Home' for `src/pages/index.js`, 'About Us' for `src/pages/about.js` and so on.

Comment: Where did you find the `exports.data` idea? Gatsby uses babel so you can do `export const data = {}`, but I haven't found the `data` export anywhere.

Comment: Within a Github issue about Gatsby JSX data exports: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3795

Comment: From reading that issue, this approach has been deprecated in favour of the [gatsby-transformer-javascript-frontmatter](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-transformer-javascript-frontmatter)

Answer (score 0):

The `data` export is parsed by the [transformer-javascript-static-exports](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-transformer-javascript-static-exports) package, which is deprecated in favour of [transformer-javascript-frontmatter](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-transformer-javascript-frontmatter).

The docs explain how to query the data.

```js
export const frontmatter = {
  title: "Choropleth on d3v4",
  written: "2017-05-04",
  layoutType: "post",
  path: "choropleth-on-d3v4",
  category: "data science",
  description: "Things about the choropleth.",
};
```

Then you could query the data like:

```
{
  allJsFrontmatter {
    edges {
      node {
        data {
          error
          path
          title
          written
          category
          description
          updated
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you use the normal query pattern to get the data into your template.

But you could just as easily have a `config.js` file that you import inside our components and use the variables directly.